# Haskell: Better way of writing Maybe Endo?

Tags: haskell, option-type, monoids

I have just discovered the Endo type thanks to the [network-api-support](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-api-support-0.1.0) package and I have found the need to be able to throw Maybe values into Endo's. As a result I have written a function called maybeEndo. Here is an example of it being used:

```
setProxy :: Proxy -> RequestTransformer
setProxy (Proxy pHost pPort) = Endo $ addProxy pHost pPort

maybeEndo :: (a -> Endo b) -> Maybe a -> Endo b
maybeEndo _ Nothing = Endo id
maybeEndo f (Just v) = f v

setPotentialProxy :: Maybe Proxy -> RequestTransformer
setPotentialProxy = maybeEndo setProxy
```

What strikes me is that this seems like something that should be encapsulated into some type of pattern already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You already found `maybe (Endo id)`. But `Endo`  is an instance of `Monoid`, and `Endo id` is its neutral element `mempty`. So you could also write more generally

```
maybeMonoid :: Monoid b => (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
maybeMonoid = maybe mempty
```

This is already quite idiomatic (plenty of hits when you google for `"maybe mempty"`). You can be even more general by using a function from `Data.Foldable`:

```
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid b) => (a -> b) -> t a -> b
```

so with this, you can write

```
setPotentialProxy :: Maybe Proxy -> RequestTransformer
setPotentialProxy = foldMap setProxy
```

(but make sure you leave in the type signature, otherwise you’ll spend too much time figuring it out later when you read the code :-)).

Comment: It has a name: foldMap! Excellent, that is exactly what I was looking for. Very nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

And as I was writing this question a solution occurred to me:

```
maybeEndo :: (a -> Endo b) -> Maybe a -> Endo b
maybeEndo = maybe (Endo id)
```

Which means that setPotentialProxy could just be:

```
setPotentialProxy :: Maybe Proxy -> RequestTransformer
setPotentialProxy = maybe (Endo id) setProxy
```

However, I have still decided to post this question because maybe there is an even more natural way to deal with this scenario. And maybe it will help somebody else.